# Why is my perl code causing my string to receive ARRAY(0xc99b3c) instead of the contents of the string?

Tags: perl, data-structures, reference

As you can see from the Perl code snippets below, I am putting the `$document` string (which contains text from a text document) into an `@document` array. Then printing out `$document` before stemming it. I am then stemming the `@document` array and then the stemmed results get put into my `$stemmed_words_anon_array` string but I get: `ARRAY(0xc99b3c)` which is like a memory address.

What am I doing wrong? My `results_stemmed.txt` also contains the `ARRAY(0xc99b3c)` inside it.

```
# Put string of main document into an array
my @document = split(' ', $document);

# Print the $document string to check it before stemming it
print $document;

open (FILE_STEM, '>results_stemmed.txt');
use Lingua::Stem qw(stem);
my $stemmed_words_anon_array = stem(@document);
# $stemmed_words_anon_array is just receiving: ARRAY(0xcbacb) here
print FILE_STEM $stemmed_words_anon_array;
close(FILE_STEM);
print $stemmed_words_anon_array;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a reference.  `@$stemmed_words_anon_array` will get you the array itself.  For more on how to deal with references in Perl, see [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File::Slurp::write_file](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3a%3aSlurp) to quickly write the entire contents of `@$stemmed_words_anon_array`:

```
use File::Slurp qw( write_file );
use Lingua::Stem qw( stem );

my $stemmed_words = stem(split ' ', $document);
write_file 'results_stemmed.txt', $stemmed_words;
print "@$stemmed_words\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly unclear documentation of the Lingua::Stem module. As a user you don't care that it's an anonymous array. You care that it's a reference to an anonymous array.

Of course, you can only ever access an anonymous array through a reference, but sometimes people don't realise that.

When I introduce references on my training course I always show people what one looks like. And tell them that they shouldn't need to know that, but at some point they WILL accidentally print a reference when they mean to print the referenced variable - so it's useful to be able to recognise it.